# Figuring out named resources/paths in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, capybara, bdd

I am new to rails and I am writing some tests using Capybara and cucumber.

```
Scenario: Successful login
  Given a user "admin@adm.com" with password "admin123"
  And I am on the sign in page

Given /^I am on the sign in page$/ do |page_name|
  visit('/users/sign_in')
  save_and_open_page
end
```

I am having trouble figuring out a way to write a named path instead of the '/users/sign_in' url.

How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is,

Go to the project root directory and run

```
rake routes
```

This will give a list of all the requests handled by rails as follows:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
    user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
```

So looking at the first column above, we see the "new_user_session"

This can be written as new_user_session_path and placed in visit() as:

```
visit(new_user_session_path)
```

And (as far as I know) it works just fine :)